# Is universe INFINITE?

Tags: universe, infinite

(My question might be asked a lot on this stack and I thank you if you mind mentioning it.)
So we know that bigbang wasn't a firecracker explosion but it was the expansion or more precise, inflation of universe. Considering that the real infinity is impossible but universe is NOT limited, so it's kind of infinite AND at the time(a fraction of a fraction of time after bigbang) of bigbang universe not only WASN'T small, also it was still infinite.
Now my question is if we get closer and closer to the "exact" time of bigbang(knowing that we actually can't so it means we're going forever)the universe was still infinite in size AND it means that universe is infinite in time
(please consider that when scientists say the universe started at 13.8 billion y.o, it is an approximation, just like when we say two things reach a temperature equilibrium and is wrong since it takes infinite time for two things to become thermally balanced. And by that I mean the length of universe was so small that we can't calculate further)
Am I wrong or missing something?

Comment: and also it means that universe is not expanding or inflating like a balloon since there is nothing beyond the universe and expansion of universe only caused the space in between objects to become larger(like what we are seeing now)

Comment: Being infinite wouldn't prevent a universe from expanding. Infinity is not a fixed size.

Comment: Can you ask on a physics or astrophysics forum? It seems astrophysics is the right way to settle this.

Comment: @D.Halsey Can you explain what you mean? To simplify, let's consider the 2-dimensional x-y plane of high school analytic geometry as our universe. It's infinite in extent. Can you explain how it could expand? Now it's true that the metric could change. so that the distance between two given points could increase over time. Yet, the space has not gotten any larger. Only the metric has changed.

Comment: @user4894 Isn't that exactly what he means? Also, isn't "distances get bigger" and "space gets larger" one and the same thing?

Comment: In the usual model of Big Bang the universe at any moment of cosmic time is a 3D sphere of finite volume. At "time zero" it was collapsed into a point singularity. Nowhere along the way was it "infinite", in space or time, although it could keep expanding forever in the future according to current estimates.

Comment: @Conifoild Friedmann universes can be either finite or infinite, depending on the total density of matter & energy. Current estimates of the parameters suggest that the universe could, in fact, be infinite. If so, it has always been infinite - never changing from finite to infinite. There are many related questions on the physics site. The best one (in my opinion) is this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point

Comment: This is an observational issue. Right now, we do not know if there is enough matter for the universe to be closed, and so finite. Get back to the astro-physics types every decade or two and see how they have progressed.

Comment: @kutschkem If I change the metric on the real line, how does that change the "size" of the real line? That's like saying my room gets larger if I use a different tape measure. That's nonsense, right? The metric does not change the underlying space. Can you see this?

Comment: @user4894 Ok sure, but if we use that interpretation, doesn't every object in the room get smaller? If I scale the metric, it seems to me I can choose two interpretations of what is happening - either the room stays the same size and  the objects get smaller or the room gets bigger and the objects stay the same size. The latter interpretation would also mean light gets slower, right?

Comment: @kutschkem If I recalibrate my speedometer so that 60 reads as 30, can I then drive 120 because it only reads 60? The traffic cop will pull me over anyway, right? *Changing the measuring device doesn't change reality*. My thesis is that many people have heard some pop science but have not actually thought things through.

Comment: @kutschkem ps -- The speed of light is the same in all reference frames. That's the cornerstone of the special theory of relativity.

Comment: @user4894 Sorry, I meant the former (room stays the same size, objects get smaller) implies light getting slower, not the latter. Which means the interpretation should be the room gets bigger. Which is what you are arguing against, I think?

Answer (score 1):

Based on current observations, it appears that the Universe is mostly empty space with a bunch of objects (matter or energy) scattered in it. So when you ask about the extent of the Universe, are you asking about the objects, or the space?

It seems plausible that *the space* just goes on forever. But it has not yet been proven that the space somehow "ends" at one point. It could also be that the space itself is finite but it loops back on itself. These are unanswered question and nobody knows the truth, it is beyond contemporary physics or cosmology (not to say there isn't interesting speculation, though).

The other question is whether the matter, as in the stars and planets and so on, goes on forever. So far it's only been observed up to a point, because the speed of light and the age of the universe are both finite. It doesn't look like there's any sign of it stopping or even thinning out. As far as you can see, the stars and the planets also seem to just go on and on. You have to keep in mind as well that looking at stars far away is looking back in time - nobody really knows what state these distant galaxies are in *today*, you can only see how they were millions of years ago.

Trivially, if the space is infinite, and since photons are fairly stable, eventually at least some rays of light would fly out very far into "space", which would push out the "boundary" of the physical "stuff" of the universe. Up to you if you consider that finite or not.

If the matter did go on forever, at a rough look it seems like that would imply there's infinite matter in the Universe. And if that came from the Big Bang, then it would imply the original, contracted Universe was infinitely massive. Alternatively, the mass could have been created somehow after the Big Bang. I believe these are all open questions as well. It is not known exactly how much mass participated in the creation of the Universe, and how likely it is that more mass or energy was created afterwards.

However, interestingly, *from our perspective* the Universe is very much finite, because we are limited by relativity in how much of it we can observe or visit. Perhaps one day, new physics will be discovered that allow us to travel faster than light or observe more distant objects, but currently there is not a known way.